# Count distinct with two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

I want to count how many distinct ids have values of 'A' AND 'B' in column Code.

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | D |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |

Data as [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yDiXrfHm)

I tried using

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM tab
WHERE CODE = 'A' AND CODE = 'B';
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) 
FROM tab AS t1 
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tab 
        WHERE ID = t1.ID AND CODE = 'A' AND CODE = 'B'
        );
```

Both methods count 0

Why is that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want count for different codes:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM tab
WHERE CODE IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY CODE ;
```

If you want common count of distinct ID paired with any of letters `A` or `B` use this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM tab
WHERE CODE IN ('A', 'B');
```

Comment: Thank you. So basically i have to use `OR` instead of `AND`, because  `AND` can only be true row-wise?

Comment: @Popppin.piet `AND` means both conditions have to be true. `OR` - any of conditions.

Comment: @Popppin.piet, since your conditions mutually exclusive, you need to use `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to count how many distinct `id`s have values `'A'` and `'B'` in column `code`.

I would recommend `group by` and `having`; this gives you the list of `ids` that have both codes (assuming no duplicate id/code).

```
select id
from tab
where code in ('A', 'B')  -- rows that have any of the two codes
group by id
having count(*) = 2       -- both codes are present in the group
```

Now we can just count how many rows the above query returns to get the output you wanted:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from (
    select id
    from tab
    where code in ('A', 'B')
    group by id
    having count(*) = 2
) t
```

I would expect this approachto perform better than the solution using `intersect`, because it scans the table only once.

---

Note that it is also possible to use `exists`, as you intended in yuour second attempt (although that's one more table scan); we would just need to fix the filtering:

```
select count(*) 
from tab as t1 
where t1.code = 'A' and exists (
    select 1
    from tab t2
    where t2.id = t1.id and t2.code = 'B'
)
```

This selects rows of code A and ensure that the given id has another row with code B.